# Please explain the "Planned package" line in Wix bootstrapper log file

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

When running a Wix bootstrapper, it writes a log file containing lines such as this one:

```
[16B8:2324][2014-12-08T11:44:21]i201: Planned package: PackageNameABC, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
```

I think I know what these two values mean:

- **state:** Whether or not the package is installed on the system
- **execute:** The action that will be taken concerning this package

But can you explain what these ones mean?

- default requested
- ba requested
- rollback
- cache
- uncache
- dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
default requested
```

The state that the Burn engine thinks the package should go to, based on things like the overall action being performed and the package's InstallCondition.

```
ba requested
```

The state returned by the BootstrapperApplication from OnPlanPackageBegin.

```
rollback
```

The action that will be taken concerning this package if an error occurred after applying this package.

```
cache
```

Whether or not to acquire the package and keep it in the package cache.

```
uncache
```

Whether or not to remove the package from the package cache.

```
dependency
```

This relates to Burn's system of reference counting packages so that if multiple Bundles install the same package, it's not removed until the last Bundle is uninstalled.